# One Windows client cannot browse the server by name (all other computers are fine)

Tags: windows

The context is a small Windows network with about 15 machines and one W2k3 R2 domain controller.
One of our clients (Win XP SP3) experiences the following issue: every so often, while browsing our Windows network, double-clicking on the domain controller computer would produce the following error message in a prompt:

> \\server is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource...

Where 'server' is our domain controller.
Now this only happens through the server's name, attempting to browse it via its IP address is perfectly fine. Everything else seems fine too, establishing Remote Desktop connections to the server (by the server name, from that client)... etc.

I noticed that restarting the **Computer Browser service** on that client temporarily solves the issue. For now the user manually does that through a batch file when the issue arises.

However this is just a workaround and I would like to fix it as this client used to not have this problem.

Comment: Does the FQDN works ? \\server.domain ? M

Comment: Have you compared the output of `ipconfig /all` on the non working machine to that of a working machine?

Comment: @Bryan
Thanks for the suggestion. There are indeed some differences, here they are: on the troublesome client I see 'Node Type: Mixed' and 'WINS Proxy Enabled: No', and on the working client: 'Node Type: Unknown' and 'WINS Proxy Enabled: Yes'.
The rest is the same on both machines, except the IP address of course.

Answer (score 0):

Check the confiuration on teh problem system to assure there are no incorrect DNS servers assigned.  You can also flush the DNS cache ipconfig /flushdns

Try nslookup \servername and see what server responds, if any.

As noted by @Bryan, check the resulst of IPCONFIG /all.

Also check that the system is not using two LAN connections like a wired and wireless link.

Comment: As said above to Bryan about ipconfig /all there is no wrong DNS server assigned for sure, the TCP/IP settings are good. Also note that it's not "really" a DNS issue as I can do all sort of things by using the server's machine name from the troublesome client. It is just browsing from the Windows Explorer that sometimes produces the issue. I can Remote Desktop it by name, I can ping it, nslookup it... etc, all this is good.